# Is there a way to change only part of an icons color in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

We are creating a smart lighting app and we want to have a lamp icon that shows the outline of the lamp type in blue and then a lightbulb inside it in the varying color.

That means that part of the icon is blue, and another part should dynamically changeable to the color we define (in the image that is the yellow part) (see picture 1)

I know that we can change icons color. I'm interested in a way to partially change the color of an icon.

I was thinking that we maybe need to custom draw the icons or something in that direction.

Happy to hear any recommendations.

[image]

Comment: i dont see any "black" part in the image you posted - maybe you mean "blue"? so blue part does not change and yellow part is drawn in different, dynamic color?

Comment: can you please check the attached images are right? Not sure what the black part is.

Comment: @pskink sorry for the confusion, yes, I meant blue, not black. I changed it in the post

Comment: can you divide every icon into 2 parts? i mean blue and yellow? if so use `Stack` with two `Image` children, where yellow image uses `color:` and `colorBlendMode:`

Comment: I am not sure how to combine them then. Can you just overlay them over one another?

Comment: use `Stack` with two `Image` children, where "yellow" `Image` uses `color: someColor` and `colorBlendMode: BlendMode.srcATop` (or `srcIn`)

Comment: I will try that! Thank you for the idea!

Comment: make sure that both images are the same size: otherwise they will not match after possible scaling

Comment: @pskink Worked perfectly. If you want to add that as an answer I'm happy to accept it for you!:)

Comment: great, write a self answer then ;-) btw what blend mode did you use?

Comment: I did not even need a blend mode. I just have two .png Images in a Stack, which don't overlap:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Stack of Images. In my example "*_00" is the static blue part, while the image ending on "*_01" is the changing part. We can change the color of the second one with a slider giving it different ARGB values.

```
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/lamp_icons/ceiling_lamp_00.png',
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 63, 115, 137),
                    scale: 1,
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/lamp_icons/ceiling_lamp_01.png',
                    color: sliderOrange,
                    scale: 1,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a method, the icon should be of the `.svg` type, but I do not expect that you will be able to access a certain color in it.

There is another way to create a set of `.svg icons` to avoid the problem of clarity with different screen size, and create for each **icons** several different possibilities according to your requirement

In this method, you can add all the possibilities in an array based on the event in which the user calls the required icon.

Hope this thing can help you

Comment: Hey, a good answer to the problem I asked. I think I did not ask my question specifically enough. I have a range of 100 different color values, so this way is rather impractical. But definitely works with fewer values!

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create the png in different sizes and add that in the respective android and ios assets and dont forget to change the name of the file name in manifesto

Comment: I can't see how this answers my question. Please re-read my question again.